# Subtracting derived columns from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, seet and fees, I need to select total paid from fees and subtract it from payable in seet.

I tried it with the below query, anyone who can rectify it please?

I get this error:

> every derived table must have its own alias

```
SELECT   (payable - pay) as balance 
FROM     (SELECT  sum(paid) AS pay 
           FROM   fees 
           WHERE  adm = '5685')
          UNION ALL 
          SELECT payable
           FROM   seet 
           WHERE  term = 'term1') 
         )as t1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT (SELECT payable   FROM seet WHERE term = 'term1') -
       (SELECT sum(paid) FROM fees WHERE  adm = '5685') as balance
```